# how to increase volume in AVSpeechUtterance in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechutterance

All 
I use my project AVSpeechUtterance for text to speech when I run in a simulator is work fine but when I run in my device speech volume is very slow here my code ...

```
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Good night all")

    if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "LNG") == "Eng"
    {
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
    }
    else
    {
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "de-DE")
    }

    utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
    utterance.volume = 1
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synth.speak(utterance)
```

Comment: I think you don't need this two line of code: 
`utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate`
`utterance.volume = 1`

Comment: i also remove it, but still not working

Comment: And I use headphone it works fine and I also try other devices problem is same voice very slow